# Can iMacros log errors in a file?

Tags: javascript, imacros

I don't know if it's only hidden or something. I am using imacros addon on firefox.
If it is none, I'm not sure if the developers of iMacro were that great because they did not think of logging functionality. They should have known that it is essential for tracking during testing and execution. iimDisplay is not enough since they are overriden during the next iimDisplay.

Can someone please help me how can I track/log imacros? I'm having hard time making my scripts

Answer (score -1):

Yes. But you need to use JavaScript.

Example

```
ret = iimPlay(macroExample);

if(ret<0)
{
WriteFile("C:\\errorlog.txt",ret);
}
```

But you need WriteFile function for this.

Comment: and the `WriteFile` function falls from heaven?